# Is there a way to set part of the content as read only in Ace editor?

Tags: javascript, ace-editor

Is it possible to introduce one or more input text into Ace Editor?

I saw that with the Range property I can block some code .

My intention is to show part of a code within the editor and the user can only edit certain area .

For example:

```
<html>
<(ZONE EDITABLE)></head>
<body>
<p><(ZONE EDITABLE)>
<(ZONE EDITABLE)>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

there is no really good method to do this. You can add a listener for beforeExec and prevent commands that are in readonly range. Search for readOnly in ace-discuss group (e.g [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ace-discuss/WuwAVBmJbKA/S0JATp6jcIgJ) and [this](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ace-discuss/bPgprC955WI/-1l32WGtXyQJ))

[cloud9 repl](https://github.com/c9/c9.ide.ace.repl/blob/f3a62c1f/repl.js#L273) does something similar too.